# Java InputVerifier find component who causes the "focus lost"

Tags: java, swing, inputverifier

I have an `InputVerifier` for a `jTextField` and of course the `InputVerifier` is triggered when I loose the focus of the text field for example through clicking on a button.

If I would use a `FocusListener` I could do:

```
focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
e.getOppositeComponent()
}
```

which gives me the component which is the reason that the focus is lost in this case the clicked button.

Is there a way to do something like this in an `InputVerifier` too ?
Basically I need to know if the reason that the `InputVerifier` is triggered is because a button was pressed.

Comment: Not really the point of an `InputVerifier`

Answer (score 2):

> Basically I need to know if the reason that the InputVerifier is triggered is because a button was pressed.

If you want to prevent the verification when you click a specific button then you can use:

```
button.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget( false );
```